# CSS accent-color Fallback For Safari and IE 11

Tags: css, cross-browser, accent-color

Looking for a fallback solution to the accent-color fallback. Specifically the following

```
input[type="range"], input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
  accent-color: #00FFFF;
}
```

Comment: This might help you: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

Comment: Thanks Azu, But I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't involve creating or applying new classes or elements. I need something that I can apply to the existing elements.